# Copy data from excel - JQWidgets Grid

Tags: jquery, jqxgrid, jqwidget

Iam trying to copy and paste data in jqGrid from excel .Grid Properties used :

```
         width: '1200px',
         height: '600px',
        sortable: true,
        sortmode: "many",
        filterable: true,
        source: dataAdapter,
        editable: true,
        enabletooltips: true,
        selectionmode: 'multiplecellsadvanced',
        filtermode: 'excel',
        autoshowfiltericon: false,
        enablebrowserselection: true,
```

Copied rows are getting over ridden in the grid instead of extending the count size of rows so that new rows can be copied . any work around for this situation .